# Populate html code from Google Spreadsheet using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, spreadsheet

Is it posible to populate html code from Google Spreadsheet using Javascript and HTML?
I am designing an app and I am hosting  it on Google appspot. I want to store the content of my website in a Google Spreadsheet which will act like a database.I don't know if this is possible because I've seen this using PHP or getting data from a Google Spreadsheet into a table whereas in my case, even the title if the page as well as the opg variable are stored in the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you seen the Google Spreadsheets API? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not get through the wide range of information. I tried using this `code`<div id="Title"></div><script type="text/javascript"> function displayContent(json) { document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$Title.$t; } </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Ao8b_CuYOtn8dHJiclhOUHZ2UERSMDh0dl9LZU9vWHc/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=displayContent”> </script> `code` but this shows the script in the title

Comment: This question makes it unclear whether you are storing just data in the spreadsheet, thinking about storing HTML markup in the spreadsheet, or rendering the spreadsheet directly in a web page. You need to clarify that. I.E. One moment you talk about HTML code - next minute act like a database.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's very much possible. for example, if you want to populate a drop down from your spreadsheet then try this:

```
HTML element: 
<div id = "mydata"></div>

Java Script Function:    
function dropdown() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = data;
}).dropdown();
}
App Script Function:
function dropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('KEY');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DD');
  var limit = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, limit, 1).getDisplayValues();
  var drop = '<select id = "dropdown"><option value="">Choose Sector</option>';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] != '') {
      drop += "<option value = '" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
    }
  }
  drop += '</select>*';
  return drop;
}
```